# Azure Logic Apps (Standard) workflows getting deleted when I redeploy Logic App IaC part, how to avoid this?

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-logic-apps, azure-rm-template, azure-bicep

I set up a Logic App in IaC in the following way:

```
param environmentType string
param location string
param storageAccountSku string
param vnetIntegrationSubnetId string
param storageAccountTempEndpoint string
param ResourceGroupName string

/// Just a single minimum instance to start with and max scaling of 3 ///
var minimumElasticSize = 1
var maximumElasticSize = 3
var name = 'somename'
var logicAppName = 'logic-app-${name}-${environmentType}'

/// Storage account for service ///
resource logicAppStorage 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2019-06-01' = {
  name: 'st4logicapp${name}${environmentType}'
  location: location
  kind: 'StorageV2'
  sku: {
    name: storageAccountSku
  }
  properties: {
    allowBlobPublicAccess: false
    accessTier: 'Hot'
    supportsHttpsTrafficOnly: true
    minimumTlsVersion: 'TLS1_2'
  }
}

/// Existing temp storage for extracting variables ///
resource storageAccountTemp 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2021-08-01' existing = {
  scope: resourceGroup(ResourceGroupName)
  name: 'tmpst${environmentType}'
}

/// Dedicated app plan for the service ///
resource servicePlanLogicApp 'Microsoft.Web/serverfarms@2021-02-01' = {
  name: 'plan-${name}-logic-app-${environmentType}'
  location: location
  sku: {
    tier: 'WorkflowStandard'
    name: 'WS1'
  }
  properties: {
    targetWorkerCount: minimumElasticSize
    maximumElasticWorkerCount: maximumElasticSize
    elasticScaleEnabled: true
    isSpot: false
    zoneRedundant: ((environmentType == 'prd') ? true : false)
  }
}

// Create log analytics workspace
resource logAnalyticsWorkspacelogicApp 'Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces@2021-06-01' = {
  name: '${name}-logicapp-loganalytics-workspace-${environmentType}'
  location: location
  properties: {
    sku: {
      name: 'PerGB2018' // Standard
    }
  }
}

/// Log analytics workspace insights ///
resource applicationInsightsLogicApp 'Microsoft.Insights/components@2020-02-02' = {
  name: 'application-insights-${name}-logic-${environmentType}'
  location: location
  kind: 'web'
  properties: {
    Application_Type: 'web'
    Flow_Type: 'Bluefield'
    publicNetworkAccessForIngestion: 'Enabled'
    publicNetworkAccessForQuery: 'Enabled'
    Request_Source: 'rest'
    RetentionInDays: 30
    WorkspaceResourceId: logAnalyticsWorkspacelogicApp.id
  }
}

// App service containing the workflow runtime ///
resource siteLogicApp 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2021-02-01' = {
  name: logicAppName
  location: location
  kind: 'functionapp,workflowapp'
  properties: {
    httpsOnly: true
    siteConfig: {
      appSettings: [
        {
          name: 'FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION'
          value: '~3'
        }
        {
          name: 'FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME'
          value: 'node'
        }
        {
          name: 'WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION'
          value: '~12'
        }
        {
          name: 'AzureWebJobsStorage'
          value: 'DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=${logicAppStorage.name};AccountKey=${listKeys(logicAppStorage.id, '2019-06-01').keys[0].value};EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net'
        }
        {
          name: 'WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING'
          value: 'DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=${logicAppStorage.name};AccountKey=${listKeys(logicAppStorage.id, '2019-06-01').keys[0].value};EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net'
        }
        {
          name: 'WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE'
          value: 'app-${toLower(name)}-logicservice-${toLower(environmentType)}a6e9'
        }
        {
          name: 'AzureFunctionsJobHost__extensionBundle__id'
          value: 'Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle.Workflows'
        }
        {
          name: 'AzureFunctionsJobHost__extensionBundle__version'
          value: '[1.*, 2.0.0)'
        }
        {
          name: 'APP_KIND'
          value: 'workflowApp'
        }
        {
          name: 'APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY'
          value: applicationInsightsLogicApp.properties.InstrumentationKey
        }
        {
          name: 'ApplicationInsightsAgent_EXTENSION_VERSION'
          value: '~2'
        }
        {
          name: 'APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING'
          value: applicationInsightsLogicApp.properties.ConnectionString
        }
        {
          name: 'AzureBlob_connectionString'
          value: 'DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=${storageAccountTemp.name};EndpointSuffix=${environment().suffixes.storage};AccountKey=${listKeys(storageAccountTemp.id, storageAccountTemp.apiVersion).keys[0].value}'
        }
        {
          name: 'azurequeues_connectionString'
          value: 'DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=${storageAccountTemp.name};EndpointSuffix=${environment().suffixes.storage};AccountKey=${listKeys(storageAccountTemp.id, storageAccountTemp.apiVersion).keys[0].value}'
        }
      ]
      use32BitWorkerProcess: true
    }
    serverFarmId: servicePlanLogicApp.id
    clientAffinityEnabled: false
  }

  /// VNET integration so flows can access storage and queue accounts ///
  resource vnetIntegration 'networkConfig' = {
    name: 'virtualNetwork'
    properties: {
      subnetResourceId: vnetIntegrationSubnetId
      swiftSupported: true
    }
  }
}
```

This all goes well and the Standard Logic App gets deployed.

Next, I define some workflows via azure pipelines (via zipdeploy) with code:

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - '*'

pool:
  name: "Ubuntu hosted"

stages:
- stage: logicAppBuild
  displayName: 'Logic App Build'
  jobs:
  - job: logic_app_build
    displayName: 'Build and publish logic app'
    steps:

    - task: CopyFiles@2
      displayName: 'Create project folder'
      inputs:
        SourceFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/logicapp'
        Contents: |
          **
        TargetFolder: 'project_output'

    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      displayName: 'Create project zip'
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/project_output'
        includeRootFolder: false
        archiveType: 'zip'
        archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
        replaceExistingArchive: true

    - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
      displayName: 'Publish project zip artifact'
      inputs:
        targetPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
        artifactName: 'artifectdev'
        publishLocation: 'pipeline'   

- stage: logicAppDeploy
  displayName: 'Logic app deployment'
  jobs:
  - job: logicAppDeploy
    displayName: 'Deploy the Logic apps'
    steps:
    - task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
      inputs:
        buildType: 'current'
        artifactName: 'artifectdev'
        targetPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'

    - task: AzureFunctionApp@1 # Add this at the end of your file
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: SC-DEV
        appType: functionApp # default is functionApp
        appName: logic-app-name-dev
        package: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/**/*.zip
```

Running the IaC code first in a pipeline (called in a main.bicep with some other infra code)  results in successful deployment of the LogicApp. After then running the pipeline with the zip-deploy, the flows defined in the `logicapp` directory get deployed well, connections and all.

However, when the IaC pipeline is run again, all my defined workflows that were deployed with the zip-deploy in the second pipeline, are now gone. Even if I don't change anything in the IaC code.

Is there any way to circumvent this? It is totally unworkable for me to have this happen every time I deploy IaC code (for instance when adding some app setting).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sharing the resolution as discussed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1035265/index.html) if someone looking for the similar issue.

For the zip deploy you need to use the AzureFunctionApp task with workflowapp apptype

```
task: AzureFunctionApp@1
displayName: Deploy Logic App Workflows
inputs:
azureSubscription: ${<!-- -->{variables.azureSubscription}}
appName: $(pv_logicAppName)
appType: 'workflowapp'
package: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/LogicApps/$(Build.BuildNumber).zip'
deploymentMethod: 'zipDeploy'
```